# Angular Reading JSON file

Tags: angular

Using angular 7
What mistake I am doing here? I am trying to read json file sitting in assets folder

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

this.http.get('./assets/490.json').subscribe(data => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) ;
    });
```

*ERROR {body: {…}, url: "./assets/490.json", headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found"}*

[image]

Comment: Well the error is quite clear: 404 Not Found. The server doesn't have anything at the URL you used.

Comment: @JBNizet if I do http://localhost:4200/assets/490.json . I am able to view the file

Comment: Then use `/assets/490.json` as your URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular 7 with the CLI, then you need to add the folder here:

```
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "api",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
```

This is part of the angular.json file.

Rest should work fine.

Comment: currently its like "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],